# Out-projected type ... prohibits the use of 'public open fun .... defined in FooTable

Tags: kotlin

I have the following class:

```
abstract class FooTable<M, D> where M : IModel, D : IDto {

    ///...

    fun getTableData(models: ArrayList<M>): ArrayList<D> {
        // ...
    }

}
```

And I have another class using it like:

```
abstract class FooPage<M, F> where M : IModel, F : IFilter {
    abstract val table: FooTable<M, out IDto>
```

Then somewhere in my code I'm trying to do:

```
page.table.getTableData(arrayListOf(m1, m2)).first()
```

And it is giving me:

> Out-projected type `FooTable<out IModel, out IDto>` prohibits the use of `public final fun getTableData(models: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<M> /* = java.util.ArrayList<M> */): kotlin.collections.ArrayList<D> /* = java.util.ArrayList<D> */` defined in `com.menighin.example.models.FooTable`

Here is a fiddle with the problem: https://pl.kotl.in/ryirJJH9m

The code is:

```
interface IModel

interface IDto

interface IFilter

class Model : IModel

class Dto : IDto

class Filter : IFilter

class FooTable<M, D> where M : IModel, D : IDto {
    fun getTableData(models: List<M>): ArrayList<D> {
        return ArrayList()
    }

    fun testPage(masterModel: IModel, thisPage: FooPage<out IModel, out IFilter>) {
        thisPage.table.getTableData(arrayListOf(masterModel)) // Error here
    }

    fun testTable(masterModel: IModel, masterTable: FooTable<out IModel, out IDto>) {
        masterTable.getTableData(arrayListOf(masterModel)) // And error here
    }
}

class FooPage<M, F> where M : IModel, F : IFilter {
    val table: FooTable<M, out IDto> = FooTable()
}


fun main() {

    val page = FooPage<Model, Filter>()

    val a = page.table.getTableData(arrayListOf())

    println("Hello, world!!!")
}
```

Basically there is a function in my `FooTable` in which I need to get reference for another Table and get its data. I guess I could pass in the data already but I'm curiou why this isn't working now...

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519921/out-projected-type-arraylist-prohibits-the-use-of-public-open-fun-addinde) that if I could change `abstract val table: FooTable<M, out IDto>` to `abstract val table: FooTable<M, Any>` it would be ok... But, as far as I know, I can't because the definition of `FooTable` is strict about the second parameter implementing `IDto`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you use `ArrayList` as the declared type? I think this would work if you used `List` since it's read-only and can be out-projected.

Comment: I changed to `fun getTableData(models: List<M>): List<D>` but now the line `page.table.getTableData(listOf(m1, m2)).first()` is giving me the error of `Type Mismatch: Required List<Nothing> found List<IModel>`

Comment: You'll get much better help, or even solve it yourself, if you prepare an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the advice Marko. I edited my answer witth an MCVE

Comment: I can't see any MCVE...

Comment: Under that link there's almost nothing, which just underlines our policy here: paste your MCVE into the question, not a link to it.

Comment: I don't get it... I posted a fiddle with a code example showing the problem so anyone can even play around the code... But it's better to paste the code here where you can't edit and don't have any hints...? Ok, I pasted the code... .-.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `testTable` function you specify that `masterTable`'s first generic type restriction (`IModel`) is `out`. If you change the declaration to this it compiles:

`fun testTable(masterModel: IModel, masterTable: FooTable<in IModel, out IDto>)`

(Alternatively, specify neither `in` nor `out`.)

This is explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) (though does take a bit getting your head round). I think that your existing code (with the `IModel` generic type restriction of `out`) states that the `masterTable` argument produces `IModel`s, but there's no rules about what it takes in. Therefore the error (at least in IntelliJ) is:

Type mismatch. Required `List<Nothing>`. Found `List<IModel>`.

Because the compiler doesn't know what `masterTable` can take in, it can't be sure that it could take in the `IModel` you're trying to pass into the `getTableData` method.